# Annoying sudden elimination of the WHOLE content of notebook

Tags: notebooks

I was editing a notebook which contained heavy graphics and often stopped up but always responded after a while. I of course saved at every step to avoid losing work. Unfortunately after running a command it kept completely stuck and Windows forcibly closed it. The surprise came when looking back to it and realizing that now the file (which was more than 50 MB) is 1 KB, so the whole work is completely lost !!! and I just get the following message.

[image]

I can't describe how disappointed I feel after losing so many hours of labor in a totally unexpected manner.

Any ideas about a possible retrieval ?

Comment: Not sure, but I’ve had this experience before.  Because of it, I built a backup button that backs all my files with one click.  It was worth building it as I’ve lost my work many times.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @Bflat So no hope to recover the text of the commands ?

Comment: I’m not sure.  You might try opening with a text editor to see if there is anything there.  But really, consider building something to protect your investment.  Mathematica is awesome but it can be quirky sometimes which is scary when you e invested a lot of time.  Trust me… I’ve learned hard way.

Comment: @Bflat text editor shows the same (useless) lines as Mathematica.

Comment: If you were working within a cloud directory, such as Dropbox, there may be saved copies you can recover there. That’s the only way I’ve been able to recover from such catastrophes.  If not, my best advice is to try and rewrite what you’ve done while it is still fresh in your mind.

Comment: Do you have any kind of backup running?  You will likely find some recovery (if possible) outside of Mathematica itself.

Comment: You can try to restore it.  See https://support.wolfram.com/12423?src=mathematica#:~:text=In%20case%20notebooks%20become%20corrupted%2C%20Mathematica%20provides%20a,Follow%20these%20steps%20to%20repair%20a%20corrupted%20notebook%3A.  Also, see this thread:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256941/i-have-a-problem-when-i-try-to-open-my-mathematica-fille/256946#256946

Comment: Tangentially related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127701/280